# How to add objects to array only if not exist

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c

I got an array of objects like: Obj1 = {idUser: 1, lat:19.0000, lng:-99.0000, active: true}. It is in order to monitor some users, so if one user leaves it changes its attribute active value from true to false and I have to remove it from the array, or if some user changes its location only the attribute coordinates value change. At this point I've already achieve it, the thing is when a user that is not registered arrives I need to add it to the array but it adds the user as many times as the idUser doesn't match with the existing ones and I need to add it only one time.

Here is an example of the code I'm using:

```
    User *u3 = [[User alloc] initWithIdUser:@3 lat:19.417210 lng:-99.163552 active:@"true"];

for (User *u in users) { 
    if ([u3.idUser isEqualToValue:u.idUser] && [u3.active isEqualToString:@"false"]) {
        NSLog(@"User leaves");
        [users removeObject:u];
    } else if ([u3.idUser isEqualToValue:u.idUser] && [u3.active isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
        NSLog(@"User changed location");
        [u setCoordinate:u3.coordinate];
    } else if (![u3.idUser isEqualToValue:u.idUser] && [u3.active isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
        NSLog(@"New user...");
        [users arrayByAddingObject:u3];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it will help you.

> ```
> // array of all active users id
> NSArray* idUsersArray =  [users valueForKey:@"idUser"];
> ```

```
// check if user already exist or not
if ([idUsersArray containsObject:u3.idUser]) {

    // get index of user
    NSUInteger index = [idUsersArray indexOfObject:u3.idUser];

    if ([u3.active isEqualToString:@"false"]) {
        [users removeObjectAtIndex:index];
         NSLog(@"User leaves");
    } else {
        User* u = [users objectAtIndex:index];
        [u setCoordinate:u3.coordinate];
        NSLog(@"User changed location");
    }
} else {
    // add user into users array
    [users arrayByAddingObject:u3];
    NSLog(@"New user...");
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, it's what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the new data will be added many times, because that's what the code you wrote is trying to do. You'll probably also run into problems because an array shouldn't be modified while a fast iterator is running.

An NSDictionary  is a much much better data structure. You'd probably want NSInteger and BOOL for the "idUser" and "active" members.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check the user against all users in another loop. Create another function

```
-(BOOL)canAddNewUser:(User*)user {
  for (User *u in users) { 
    if ((u.idUser isEqualToValue:user.idUser)&&([user.active isEqualToString:@"true"])) {
      return YES;
    }
  }
  return NO;
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
User *u3 = [[User alloc] initWithIdUser:@3 lat:19.417210 lng:-99.163552 active:@"true"];

for (User *u in users) { 
    if ([u3.idUser isEqualToValue:u.idUser] && [u3.active isEqualToString:@"false"]) {
        NSLog(@"User leaves");
        [users removeObject:u];
    } else if ([u3.idUser isEqualToValue:u.idUser] && [u3.active isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
        NSLog(@"User changed location");
        [u setCoordinate:u3.coordinate];
    } 
}

if ([self canAddNewUser:u3]) {
    NSLog(@"New user...");
    [users arrayByAddingObject:u3];
}
```